# Java StringTokenizer with 2 params?

Tags: java

I know using StringTokenizer is not a great idea, but I need to use it. Is it possible to "destroy" all the ' ' and '\t' characters and split the string? For example:

"Hello \t \t this\tis great"

Should be:

"Hello"
"this"
"is"
"great"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to split the string at whitespace, it is a **lot** easier than you think.

```
String string = "Hello \t \t this\tis great";
String[] splitedString = string.split("\\s+"); // Split at every instance of multiple whitespace in a row.
```

If you want to split only at multiple tabs/spaces:

```
String[] splitedString = string.split("[\\t ]+");
```

If you really need to use StringTokenizer, which should never ever be used in the present time,...

```
StringTokenizer uselessTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(string, "[\\t ]+");
```

Answer (score 1):

`StringTokenizer("Hello \t \t this\tis great")` will construct an `Enumeration` from which you can extract the substrings you're looking for.

However, I can't imagine why you would want to do this, considering that `"Hello \t \t this\tis great".split("\\s")` will do the same thing but return a `String[]`, which is much more useful.